# Cannot deploy angular project in heroku through nodejs server working fine in local

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

While deploying angular app through nodejs server I cannot deploy due to "

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall /tmp/build_421fbb1ae8571a2474c26f3622e559a7/node_modules/@angular/cli
>   node ./bin/ng-update-message.js
>          internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
>          throw err;
>          ^
>          Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/build_421fbb1ae8571a2474c26f3622e559a7/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/
>   "

Full error log please check : https://gist.github.com/ArkaBando/962ee23a1c3dd386211676cda300ec58/revisions

[Image for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wle1R.png.)
For full source code please refer : https://github.com/ArkaBando/angular-git_repoview_app .

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding @angular-devkit/build-angular to your dependecies as well in package.json right now its only in devDependencies. I’ll explain further if it works.

Comment: I have added @angular-devkit/build-angular to dependency too but same error https://gist.github.com/ArkaBando/962ee23a1c3dd386211676cda300ec58/revisions is occurring .

Comment: What is happening is during installation of @angular/cli there is a postinstall script. You can see it in you node_modules/@angular/cli/package.json. The post install looks for ./bin/ng-message-update.js, which is not there as you could see. This issue here suggests a solution, try that https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10728

Comment: It is working locally fine with all post install script using `sudo npm run postinstall`
 but not in heroku

Comment: Hmm it’s strange that npm install tries installing the angular/cli in heroku; did you set NODE_ENV to production in herokus environment?